# asyncio does not stop on completing all execution

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I added an error handler in the asyncio following code. but now the code just hangs and keeps waiting for the error_event to set. If all the tasks are executed without errors, this code just keeps waiting indefinitely.

Can someone help to terminate the following code on success and also stop all the tasks if exceptions are observed during any of the task execution?

```
import asyncio

async def task_1():
    try:
        for i in range(5):
            print('This is running TASK_1')
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
    except Exception as e:
        error_event.payload = e
        error_event.set()
        raise


async def task_2():
    try:
        for i in range(2):
            print('This is running TASK_2')
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
    except Exception as e:
        error_event.payload = e
        error_event.set()
        raise


async def error_handler():
    await error_event.wait()
    e = error_event.payload
    print("Observed Exception:", e)
    raise e

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
error_event = asyncio.Event()
try:
    loop.create_task(task_1())
    loop.create_task(task_2())
    loop.run_until_complete(error_handler())
except Exception as e:
    loop.close()
    print(type(e).__name__)
```

Comment: I don't get the point of the error handler. Why add this indirection instead of directly watching the tasks for errors?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi
I am new to asyncio, Could you please explain with an example? Thanks